# How to submit a node form with AJAX Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

How can I set up a node form to submit via ajax. I can't find examples that show how to do this explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article.

http://drupal.org/node/752056

It should get you started.