# I want to save and view the node content in the same page without page refresh using content types

Tags: views, nodes, ajax

I have to create content type as CELL. **CELL** content type have some fields. I want to show the fields in the node create page.

[image: Refer the Image]

How to save the data without page refresh. How to view the saved content also using views. Anyone guide to me?

I have created it cell view block and show to only node/add/cell page.

But i want to save the data without page refresh and also get the data from db without page refresh. Please anyone guide to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to submit a node form with AJAX Drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/how-to-submit-a-node-form-with-ajax-drupal-7)

Comment: @herci I disagree - apparently OP here wants to see both edit form and content, and that's not quite what we see  in question you linked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here I have some material for you that will help you to save node form through ajax without refreshing the page at https://www.drupal.org/node/752056 . Here is also another link that will clear your idea about ajax enabled form at https://www.drupal.org/node/264429 .
2. The solution of second part of your question that shows the node value is so simple. Just make a block views containing your required field from your selected content type and then place that block into your current admin theme at desired region. Don't forget to apply restriction to only show to specific content type.